# How to change the URL redirection of method_decorator(login_required)

Tags: django

i added method decorator in my project for redirect user if they are not connected, the problem is the redirect go to " /accounts/login/?next=/organisation/collaborator/ " instead of " /userprofile/login/?next=/organisation/collaborator/ . Can i change that ?

```
from django.conf import settings
.
.
.
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class CollaboratorView(View):

template = 'team/collaborator.html'
context = {
    'title': 'Planificator',
    'title_page': "Teams",
    'description_page': "Collaborator profil",
}
def get(self, request, collaborator_id=None):

    context = self.basecontext()

    if collaborator_id is not None:
        context.update({
            'collaborator_choosen': collaborator_id,
        })

    return render(
        request,
        self.template,
        context=context
    )
```

Urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('home.urls')),
    path('organisation/', include('organisation.urls')),
    path('grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^userprofile/', include('userprofile.urls')),
]
```

i ddin't have LOGIN_URL in settings.py
settings.py

```
'''
Django settings for planificator project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os


from .menus import NAV_MENU_LEFT
#from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
#User = get_user_model()

# from tfs import TFSAPI

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '2z7308i6o1z6u5m2%0hvznns+60-zgv)-k&jd9c&c5ko!^j=mk'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'grappelli',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'home.apps.HomeConfig',
    'organisation.apps.OrganisationConfig',
    'userprofile.apps.UserprofileConfig',
    'menu_generator',
    'import_export',
    'debugtools',
    #'userprofile',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'planificator.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'planificator/templates/')),
            # (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'extras/templates/')),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                # 'planificator.context_processors.baseurl',
            ],      
            'builtins': [                                     # Add this section
                "debugtools.templatetags.debugtools_tags",   # Add this line
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'planificator.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'userprofile.UserProfile'

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Add these new lines
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

if os.getenv('DJANGO_ENV') == 'prod':
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
    STATIC_UPLOADS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/uploads')
else:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
    STATIC_UPLOADS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles/uploads')

# Use DefaultCollection
#tfsclient = TFSAPI("https://tfs.transport-systemes-solutions.fr/tfs/", user="lm52121853", password="MaTh3uX_1119")

GRAPPELLI_ADMIN_TITLE = 'Planificator Admin'
```

Comment: Can you please share your urls.py and also related part(LOGIN_URL) in your settings.py.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
@method_decorator(login_required(login_url='/userprofile/login/'))
```

Comment: It works i didn't know i can put login_required(login_url='/userprofil/login/') inside a method decorator Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

for some reasons the solution by @branko didnt work for me. however got help from [this thread](https://django-users.narkive.com/c5M68WQJ/method-decorator-login-required-but-how-to-add-login-url-login-to-login-required) to add LOGIN_URL and LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL in settings.py.

```
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/login/'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@method_decorator(login_required(login_url='/user/login/'), name='dispatch')
class Dashboard(TemplateView):
template_name = 'dashboard/dashboard.html'

#Settings.py file
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/login/'
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly. Also please include an explanation, code only answers are not high quality.